# Can't get test coverage for function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need help with getting code coverage for the following function. I'm not sure how to get into the code highlighted below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZuRL.png)

```
 submitContactForm(): void {
 const contactData: ContactData = {
  'name': this.name.value,
  'email': this.email.value,
  'subject': this.subject.value,
  'description': this.description.value,
  'userId': null,
  'siteSource': this.authService.getSiteSource()
};

***this.xyzService.submitQuery(contactData).subscribe(
  resp => {
    console.log('Contact Us got a positive response');
    console.log(resp);
    this.alertService.success('Success', 'Your message has been sent successfully. We will reply to you as soon as possible');
  },
  err => {
    this.alertService.showAlert(err);
    console.log('Contact Us got a ERROR response');
    console.log(err);
  }***
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like :

```
  component.submitContactForm()   
  fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(result).toEqual(desiredValue);
   });
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm quite new to angular so I'm not sure what exactly to expect from xyzService, heres the method for submitQuery `submitQuery(query: Object): Observable<Response> {
    return this.siteService.postRequest(this.endpoint, 'submitQuery', null, query);
  }`

Comment: Precisely what part you are having an issue with ?What is xyzService(From what I understand,it's just a service in which submitQuery method's description is present in which case you should be having an issue with that method not service)